# Change multiple if statements

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I am starting learn python, several days ago, and many things I don't know, but I am trying.
So, I have this:

```
if setting == MAKE:
    rettt = User.make()
elif setting == MOD:
    rettt = User.mod()
elif setting == REM:
    rettt = User.rem()
```

How you think, can we change this on something like, that:

```
settings = {
'MAKE': make,
'MOD': mod,
'REM': rem
}
if setting in settings:
    rettt = User.settings()
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options:

- store method *names*, then use `getattr()` to turn the name back into a reference to the method:

  ```
  settings = {
      'MAKE': 'make',
      'MOD': 'mod',
      'REM': 'rem'
  }
  if setting in settings:
      rettt = getattr(User, settings[setting])()
  ```

  I note that at this point this becomes a simple lower-casing exercise, perhaps with a set test to ensure you can't call arbitrary methods:

  ```
  settings = {'MAKE' 'MOD', 'REM'}
  if setting in settings:
      rettt = getattr(User, setting.lower())()
  ```
- Store the bound methods in the dictionary each time:

  ```
  settings = {
      'MAKE': User.make,
      'MOD': User.mod,
      'REM': User.rem,
  }
  if setting in settings:
      rettt = settings[setting]()
  ```
- Use [`operator.methodcaller()` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller); these take a string method name and can be called with an object to call the method *on*:

  ```
  from operator import methodcaller

  settings = {
      'MAKE': methodcaller('make'),
      'MOD': methodcaller('mod'),
      'REM': methodcaller('rem')
  }
  if setting in settings:
      rettt = settings[setting](User)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getattr` to *get the attribute* from the user object. And you wouldn't need the `if` any longer:

```
settings = {
'MAKE': 'make',
'MOD': 'mod',
'REM': 'rem'
}

rettt = getattr(User, settings[setting])()
```

Note that the dictionary values should be strings, since the methods are bounded to the `User` object and you can't call them as you would unbounded functions.

Apparently, you can do without the dict:

```
rettt = getattr(User, setting.lower())()
```

Comment: not bad, i will check. in any case, it is very interest resolving

Comment: getattr() throws AttributeError unless you provide a default return value (or check the provided setting being a valid method)

Comment: @rolika: but if the `settings` dictionary is considered a correct source of method names, you'd have a `KeyError` at most.